# The liquid does not get into the pipe

Tags: fluid-simulation

The liquid does not get into the pipe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried

*Is planar* *off* , *on*
*Flip Normals* and is *planar off*

[image]

Comment: we could help you best if you would provide your blend file ...https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.   There are a lot of reasons why this happens e.g. a face in the way which we cannot see in your picture or multiple other reasons....

Comment: My suspicion would be that your Domain Resolution is set too low. It needs to be high enough to allow simulation ‘cells’ to be small enough to fit within your pipe.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=P38oAk13" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/P38oAk13/)

there is

Comment: @Chris i shared

Comment: Make sure you have applied the scale to your domain. Blender uses real world numbers for it's sims and it thinks your domain is much smaller than it is.

Answer (score 0):

ok, make these changes:

1. assure that your pipe is converted to mesh
2. add a solidify modifier to the pipe with 0.2 thickness and apply it
3. set surface thickness 0.2 in the fluid tab of the effector
4. remove velocity of inflow (because i am not sure whether it is too fast, maybe some other parameters have to be changed to make this work), so just set velocity to 0

bake again -> test

Comment: i'll try after answer you thx